# Convert a CString to an array of floats

Tags: c++, mfc, tokenize

I'm currently working with MFC to build a certain program, which requires the user to enter a series of numbers as highlighted down below in a `CString` ( let's call it aCString for simplicity).

[image]

I can convert a string or array of chars to an array of floats using 'strtok'
without problems .

But I'm struggling to convert `CString` to a string or array of chars so I can do the pre-mentioned conversion !

-I tried `strcpy`

```
strcpy(my_string, (LPCTSTR)aCString);
```

But got that error

> char *strcpy(char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 2 from
>   'LPCTSTR' to 'const char *'

I appreciate the help !

Comment: The equivalent to `strtok()` (although not destructive) is [CString::Tokenize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4ftfkd2.aspx).

Comment: Due to internationalization `CString` isn't using normal `char` as characters, but `TCHAR` which will be defined as `char` or `wchar_t` depending on the `UNICODE` macro in your project settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) class template provides the [Tokenize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4ftfkd2.aspx) member, that can be used to split an input string into individual tokens. The tokens can then be converted to floating point values using the [std::stof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function:

```
std::vector<float> ToFloats( const CString& numbers ) {
    std::vector<float> buffer;
    int start{ 0 };
    CString token = numbers.Tokenize( _T( "," ), start );
    while ( start != -1 ) {
        buffer.push_back( std::stof( { token.GetString(),
                                       static_cast<size_t>( token.GetLength() ) } ) );
        token = numbers.Tokenize( _T( "," ), start );
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget exception handling for `std::stof`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: It's odd that you single out `std::stof`. `std::vector::push_back` can throw, and so does `CStringT::Tokenize`. But that's all besides the point: The appropriate way to handle exceptions in this function is to not do anything at all. This function cannot know, whether failure to convert the input, or construct the output is tolerable or fatal. It's the caller that needs to handle exceptions, because only the caller knows.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: This function promises to return a vector of floats. If it cannot satisfy that promise, it throws an exception. Any caller up the call chain can decide, whether it can reasonably handle exceptions. This function cannot. Besides, uncaught exceptions do not *"crash"*. They call the `unexpected` handler, which by default calls `terminate`. That's a clean and deterministic shutdown.

Comment: Thanks IInspectable, I saw your comment in a different section, I have to read up on this more. The problem would be solved simply by adding `try`/`catch(...)` for `std::stof`. I don't want to close the program if the user accidentally pushes the wrong key!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: That is the wrong solution. It merely hides bugs. You may not like your program to terminate on invalid input, but you surely don't want your program to use invalid input, without even knowing about it. If you need to continue running, catch the exceptions somewhere higher up in the call chain. This function cannot (and **must not**) hide the error. It is there for a reason.

Comment: int start { 0 };  is that a typo?

Comment: @TomTom: [No](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#uniform-init).